# No puedo hacer un git add a mi proyecto con node js

Tags: nodejs, web, git, github, git-add

Recién estoy tomando un curso de nodejs y me gustaría utilizar el sistema de control de versiones git. El problema aquí es que después de hacer git init, al momento de hacer git add . me devuelve esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo sé que pues no puede abrir por alguna razón ese archivo.

**información que podría importar**

- Estoy utilizando Windows 10
- mi proyecto tiene estas dependencias:
  [image: Es lo único que he puesto en mi proyecto Node]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo general, en lo proyectos siempre se agrega un .gitignore para ignorar, por ejemplo: la carpeta "node_modules", porque no es necesario subir las dependencias, solo necesitas tu package.json para instalarlas.
Prueba creando un .gitignore y dentro coloca "node_modules" (sin comillas). Luego intenta de nuevo con "git add ."

Comment: Tiene muchísimo sentido, no conocía el .gitignore. ¿dónde se crea este archivo?

Comment: Por lo general se coloca en la raiz del proyecto. Te dejo esta imagen de ejemplo, es la estructura del framework Angular: https://amoelcodigo.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/image-1.png